Using straight as an adverb
I'm doing a worksheet where I have to identify adverbs. The sentence is "If you're running for three days straight you can't just eat energy snacks."
The correct answer is "straight" but I don't understand if it is describing the "running" or the "for three days"?

@StuartF has it. "Straight" means continuously, but applies closer to "for three days in a row" than to "running."

There's a problem with the precise definition of adverb. To some people, adverbs can modify other adverbs or adjectives as well as actual verbs (as in The rocket went straight up or He went straight home). But there's no such confusion with, for example, He's so drunk he can't walk straight.

I'd say that the phrase is "for three days straight" meaning 'for three days in a row without any sort of break, continuously" and that straight is a postmodifier of "three days" and that entire phrase adds information to the clause about the uninterrupted nature and duration of the running but is not a modifier of "running".

idiom: to do something for [time] straight. Usually,  hours, days, weeks, months, or years. It is an adverb as it describes how long you have been running without stopping.

Thank you all - that's cleared things up!

OP's query:

The sentence is "If you're running for three days straight you can't just eat energy snacks."
The correct answer is "straight" but I don't understand if it is describing the "running" or the "for three days"?

Here the meaning of straight is continuous or without a gap.
Ref. Collins dictionary.


adjective [ADJECTIVE noun].
Straight means following one after the other, with no gaps or intervals.
They'd won 12 straight games before they lost.
Synonyms: successive, consecutive, continuous, through
Straight is also an adverb.
He called from Weddington, having been there for 31 hours straight.


The given answer is correct.
"Straight" is an adverb modifying the verb phrase - "running for three days".
